# How can I increase or decrease jquery slider values with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am fairly new to JQuery and have been given a task to make my website look similar to this - [link here](http://www.thecarloanwarehouse.com/car-loan-calculator/) - this includes the JQuery Slider function that I am trying to imitate so that all the values change according to the movement direction of the slider.

However, the best I am able to come up with is from the result shown in this following code (my apologies if it looks a bit messy, I tried tidying it up as much as I can, also [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) is currently not working for me for some reason. I attempted to make the jquery slider work properly with reference from this link here - [jquery slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range) but the values do not change according to the movement direction of the slider.

Here is the code underneath of what I have done so far (including the asterisk from the scripting which indicates my previous attempts)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org./TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="en">

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styleresult.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title> Loan Result </title>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script>

$(function() {
    $( ".CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Slider").slider({
      range: true,
      min: 3000,
      max: 50000,
      values: [ 3000, 50000 ],
      step: 10,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        $( "#CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Value_Box1").val("$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
            handlevalues=($(".CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Slider").slider('values'));
        },
          change: function(event, ui) 
          {
    $( "#CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Value_Box1").val(ui.values[0]);

    }
});
});

/*
$(function() {
    $( "#CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Slider_Box1").slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 3500,
        min: 3000,
        max: 50000,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $( "#CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Value_Box1").val("$" + ui.value);
            }
        });
        $( "#CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Value_Box1").val("$" + $( "#CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Slider_Box1").slider("value") );
    });
*/

/*
$(function() {
    $('#CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Slider_Box1').slider({
        slide: function(event, ui) {
        $('#CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Value_Box1').text(ui.value).css('left', (ui.value - 0.5) + '%');
    }});
    $('#CarLoanWarehouseCalc_MinValue_Box1').text($('#CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Slider_Box1').slider('option', 'min'));
    $('#CarLoanWarehouseCalc_MaxValue_Box1').text($('#CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Slider_Box1').slider('option', 'max'));

});
*/

/*
$(function () {
    $("#CarLoanWareHouseCalc_Slider_Box1").slider({
        range: "min",
        min: 1,
        max: 10,

        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Value_Box1").text(ui.value);
        },

        change: function (event, ui) {
            alert("Yeah Yeah" + ui.value);
        }
    });
});
*/

/*
$(function() {
    $( "#CarLoanWarehouseCalc_SliderBox1").slider({
      range: true,
      min: 3000,
      max: 50000,
      values: [ 6000, 30000 ],
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        $( "#CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Value_Box1").val("$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        }
    });
    $( "#CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Value_Box1").val("$" + $( "CarLoanWareHouseCalc_Slider_Box1").slider( "values", 0 ) +
        " - $" + $( "#CarLoanWareHouseCalc_Slider_Box1" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
*/

</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="maincontent" class="Calc-page">
<h1>Car Loan 
    <strong>Calculator</strong>
</h1>
<div class="entry">
<div id="_atssh" style="visibility: hidden; height: 1px; width: 1px; position: absolute; z-index: 100000;">

</div>

<div class="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_BoxContainer" id="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Box1">
<!-- Car Loan Warehouse Title -->
<div class="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Title" id="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Title_Box1">Loan   Amount</div>
<!-- Car Loan Warehouse Desc -->
    <div class="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Desc" id="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Desc_Box1">Select the amount you wish to borrow. The Car Loan Warehouse will loan between £3,000 and £50,000</div>
<!-- Car Loan Warehouse Value -->
<div class="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Value" id="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Value_Box1">£3,500</div>
<!-- Car Loan Warehouse Value Hidden-->

<input class="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_ValueHidden" type="range" id="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_ValueHidden_Box1" value="3500" min="3000" max="50000" data-highlight="true" />

<!-- Car Loan Warehouse Slider -->
<div class="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"
```

id="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Slider_Box1">

```
</div>

<!-- Car Loan Warehouse Min Value -->
<div class="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_MinValue" id="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_MinValue_Box1">£3,000
</div>
<!-- Car Loan Warehouse Max Value -->
<div class="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_MaxValue" id="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_MaxValue_Box1">£50,000
</div>
</div>

<div class="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_BoxContainer" id="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Box2">
<!-- Car Loan Warehouse Title -->
<div class="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Title" id="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Title_Box2">Repayment Period
</div>
```

Select the loan term in number of months between 12 months and 60 months

       36
      Months

12 months



60 months

```
  <div class="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_BoxContainer" id="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Box3">
```

Credit Score

          Select the credit score example which most closely matches your circumstances

         Good

```
  <div class="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_ValueDesc" id="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_ValueDesc_Box3">Home owner or long term tenant at same address for substantial period with electoral roll record. Employed by same company or self employed for long period. Long credit history with mortgage, loans and credit cards. Few credit applications. Credit with a few missed payments, defaults or County Court Judgements.
     </div>
```

Bad

       Excellent

```
<div class="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_BoxContainer" id="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Box4">
<!-- Car Loan Warehouse Desc -->
<div class="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Desc" id="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Desc_Box4">Here is your personal financial example</div>
<!-- Car Loan Warehouse APR -->
<div class="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_APR" id="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_APR_Box4">13.9% Typical APR</div>
<!-- Car Loan Warehouse APR Hidden-->
<input class="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_APRHidden" type="hidden" id="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_APRHidden_Box4" value="">
<!-- Car Loan Warehouse Monthly Total -->
<div class="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_MonthlyTotal" id="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_MonthlyTotal_Box4">Monthly Payment £134.28</div>
<!-- Car Loan Warehouse Total -->
<div class="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Total" id="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Total_Box4">Total Repayable £4,834.00</div>
</div>

<a href="http://www.thecarloanwarehouse.com/apply-online/" title="Apply Now for Free" class="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_BoxContainer box4-apply-now" id="CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Box5">
Apply Now for FREE Decision
</a>

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS can be found from the link here: [here](http://www.thecarloanwarehouse.com/car-loan-calculator/) - just right-click on the page, go to **Inspect Element --> Sources**

Any help would be appreciated, if you need further clarification please let me know so that I can make more sense in my explanation.

Thanks

Comment: I prefer jsfiddle as well, but when it's down (as it is for me at the moment), I use http://codepen.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your question is broken up and unreadable. This makes it difficult for people to jump in and help you. Either post a jsfiddle, a codepen, or at the very least clean up your code so that it's all within one code block.

I've created a very simple codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lzfcp. It's basically the javascript that you wrote above:

```
(function() {
    $( ".CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Slider").slider({
      range: true,
      min: 3000,
      max: 50000,
      values: [ 3000, 50000 ],
      step: 10,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        $( "#CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Value_Box1").val("$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        handlevalues=$(".CarLoanWarehouseCalc_Slider").slider('values');
      },
    });
})();
```

and it works like I expect it to work. So what's the problem?